# Making a big project ipad compatible

Tags: javascript, ipad

I'm here to get some information. We have a product thats pretty big and has been around for some years. We want to keep our customers happy and one thing that has to be done is making the entire product ipad compatible. The layout is looking fine on ipad but the problem is the gestures. For example, scrollable divs, this is a big problem. Escpecially scrollable divs etc. My question is: are there any good javascript libraries that aim to getting ipad gestures to work nicely?

Comment: jQuery mobile is nice. But you could've googled that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy the iPad's look and feel I recommend you to use [jQuery Touch](http://www.jqtouch.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe jQuery Mobile will do it for you :

- http://jquerymobile.com/
  It comes with support for gestures, and it's easy to deploy !